# how to retain run configurations in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Every-time I restart my eclipse and I loose all my run configuration, can somebody help me retain them. Please let me know which file needs to be changed to retain them ?

I am using eclipse Juno

Comment: This is strange, usually all the run configurations are saved =\

Comment: It should retain the configurations. Are you sure you don't have any type of PC Freeze?

Comment: I dont have any software other than eclipse and all other required for my project

Comment: Have you tried downloading it again (without any kind of config.)?

Comment: @Christian yes I have tried it, could you please tell me in which file run configurations reside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this problem is strange but I got a work around to resolve it the configuration files reside in

> [eclipse-workspace].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core.launches

so to retain them just copy them somewhere and after that just paste at this location and in this way we can share them between workspaces as well

[Helpful link for this](http://eclipsesnippets.blogspot.in/2007/07/tip-creating-and-sharing-launch.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can export them to files. Just use `Export -> Run/Debug -> Launch Configurations`. You should export them to some directory in your workspace. Eclipse will list those launch configurations automatically under the Run As or Debug As dropdown lists.

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace [-> Startup and Shutdown]

This is how my Eclipse Kepler config looks like, maybe it helps.

[image]

Try also playing around General -> Workspace and General -> Startup and Shutdown (including sub categories)